# Does $A^\mathrm{T} A$ have a positive eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, metric-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Suppose that $A$ is a $n\times n$ real matrix. Does $A^\mathrm{T} A$ have a positive eigenvalue? Does the same hold for $A^*A:=\overline{A^\mathrm{T}}A$ if $A$ is a complex matrix?

---

This question emerges when I see the definition of 2-norm of a matrix:
$$||A||_2:=\sqrt{\lambda_{\textrm{max}}(A^{\mathrm{T}}A)}.$$

The question is: **how to make sure $\lambda_{\textrm{max}}(A^{\mathrm{T}}A)\geq 0$?** Otherwise, it is not valid to define in this way. For me, I have figured out that an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A^{\mathrm{T}}A$ is real because $(A^\mathrm{T} A)^\mathrm{T}=A^\mathrm{T}A$, *i.e.*, $A^{\mathrm{T}}A$ is symmetric. Similarly, an eigenvalue of $A^*A$ is real because $A^*A$ is an Hermite matrix. But I just have no idea how to estimate the eigenvalue, positive or negative...

Thank you very much in advance! Any help or discussion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you know that any Hermitian matrix has at least one eigenvalue (regardless of whether or not we are working over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$), it should be pretty clear that this 2-norm is well-defined. As, if $\lambda$ is any eigenvalue of $A^TA$ and $v$ is any corresponding eigenvector, $\lambda(v\cdot v)=(\lambda v)\cdot v=(A^TA v)\cdot v=(Av)\cdot (Av)\geq 0$, so $\lambda$ is automatically nonnegative (and then, by the spectral theorem, $A^T A$ has to have at least one positive eigenvalue if it is a non-zero matrix). You can use the same kind of reasoning if your matrix has complex entries, with the difference that you need to replace $A^T$ with $\overline{A^T}$.

Comment: Thank you, @Cardioid_Ass_22!